# Liquibase Db2 configruation

Tags: db2, liquibase

I am trying to get liquibase 3.10.2 on ubuntu working for the first time with Db2 warehouse.
Following the tutorial example, the H2 "liquibase update" example works fine.

Using the specified jars and the url string below, works fine with dbeaver but translating this to liquibase is providing the following error.

```
driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver 
#jars in /test1/sql
classpath: db2jcc4.jar:db2jcc_license_cu.jar
databaseClass: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

# Enter the path for your changelog file.
changeLogFile: samplechangelog.h2.sql

#### Enter the Target database 'url' information  ####
url: jdbc:db2://192.168.72.143:50000/bludb

# Enter the username for your Target database.
username: bluadmin

# Enter the password for your Target database.
password: bluadmin

#### Enter the Source Database 'referenceUrl' information ####
## The source database is the baseline or reference against which your target database is compared for diff/diffchangelog commands.

# Enter URL for the source database
referenceUrl: jdbc:db2://192.168.72.143:50000/bludb

# Enter the username for your source database
referenceUsername: bluadmin

# Enter the password for your source database
referencePassword: bluadmin


09:23:16.261 ERROR [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.Database (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @242aa8d9; liquibase.database.Database is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.Database (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @242aa8d9; liquibase.database.Database is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:125)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1341)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:303)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:159)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.Database (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @242aa8d9; liquibase.database.Database is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:259)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:149)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:90)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.Database (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @242aa8d9; liquibase.database.Database is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:187)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Updated additional info:

(1) What is the full command-line that results in the error shown?
I am issuing the simple example that is referenced in the h2 tutorial

```
jarrod@ubuntu:~/liquibase3.10.2/test1/sql$ ls -al
total 6424
drwxrwxr-x 2 jarrod jarrod    4096 Aug  1 08:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 jarrod jarrod    4096 Aug  1 08:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jarrod jarrod     218 Jul 14 05:49 blankchangelog.h2.sql
-r--r--r-- 1 jarrod jarrod 6550443 Jun 11  2019 db2jcc4.jar
-r--r--r-- 1 jarrod jarrod    1529 Jun 11  2019 db2jcc_license_cu.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jarrod jarrod    2678 Aug  1 09:23 liquibase.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 jarrod jarrod     456 Jul 14 05:49 samplechangelog.h2.sql
jarrod@ubuntu:~/liquibase3.10.2/test1/sql$ liquibase update 
15:05:37.848 DEBUG [liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor]: Opening jar:file:/home/jarrod/liquibase3.10.2/liquibase.jar!/liquibase.build.properties as liquibase.build.properties
15:05:37.868 INFO  [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: ####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
....
```

(2) What is the change log file contents
This is the same as the sample h2 change log; no changes.

```
jarrod@ubuntu:~/liquibase3.10.2/test1/sql$ cat samplechangelog.h2.sql 
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset your.name:1
create table person (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    address1 varchar(50),
    address2 varchar(50),
    city varchar(30)
)

--changeset your.name:2
create table company (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    address1 varchar(50),
    address2 varchar(50),
    city varchar(30)
)

--changeset other.dev:3
alter table person add column country varchar(2)

jarrod@ubuntu:~/liquibase3.10.2/test1/sql$
```

(3) which Db2 driver version are you using?

Bundle-Name: IBM JCC JDBC 4 Driver

(4) What exact Query works in dbeaver but fails in liquibase?

None at the moment, just trying to get the connection working.
I have a working connection in Dbeaver using the same jdbc driver, same class name, same server, database, username, password and URL template.

I'd actually happy to getting SQL errors!

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add missing facts (1) What is the full command-line that results in the error shown? (2) What is the change log file contents (3) which Db2 driver version are you using? (4) What exact Query works in dbeaver but fails in liquibase ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

liquibase 3.10.2 seems to work with Db2-LUW for me.

Try making these changes, which are documented in the text file `GETTING_STARTED.txt` .

Either move the Db2 jar files into the `lib` subdirectory of liquibase, or arrange a change to the CLASSPATH used by liquibase. For Db2-LUW the files are: `lib/db2jcc4.jar , lib/db2jcc.jar , lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar` . Your question shows you copied these files into the liquibase directory instead of the liquibase lib subdirectory.

Db2-LUW will reject the  syntax in the sample changeLogFile for H2 because Db2-LUW requires that a primary key column is not null. In the sample file, you can change `id int primary key` to `id int not null primary key` for all tables, to avoid an SQLCODE -542.

Comment: That works thanks.  I moved the jar to /lib and removed the class stuff from the properties file.   Maybe got a little ahead of myself!   Thanks again.